# Main chat room has been frozen

Tags: support, status-completed

The main photography chat room has been frozen after only 24+ hours of inactivity. Does anyone know why? The general information at SE says 14 days of inactivity will freeze a chat room.

Comment: As a note, you don't need to flag, we get notified of new Meta questions on the main site. :)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify on what Joanne said kind of indirectly, chat will freeze unless there is user generated content within the last 14 days.  Automatic posts such as the triggered question posts as well as any system notifications (such as the room being unfrozen) won't actually count as a message.  This is also why you'll sometimes see moderators forget to post a message when unfreezing a room and then it refreezes later that day when the scheduled freeze job runs.  It doesn't refreeze immediately in those cases because the batch job that freezes inactive rooms only runs occasionally (at least once a day, but it might be a few times, I'm not sure precisely how often it runs).

Answer (score 2):

The last user submitted message was quite a while ago, Feb 12th, so that's why it was frozen. I'm a bit surprised about that, given that it's the site chat, but I've now unfrozen it.